# Convert from `SolrQuery` to `SolrRequest`

Tags: solrj, solr8

Using solr8. Currently, I'm using simple solr queries like the following:

```
QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(solrQuery);
```

This is working great, but I have a new requirement to include a request-specific header to the solr endpoint. Unfortunately, `SolrQuery` doesn't support anything obvious. However, I see that `SolrRequest` does have `addHeader()`. Yay! Except now I have to convert `SolrQuery` to `SolrRequest` objects. No big deal:

```
SolrRequest solrRequest = new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
```

Except now my call to the client needs to change. Ugh.

```
NamedList<Object> namedList = solrClient.request(solrRequest);
```

And now I need to convert `NamedList<Object>` to `QueryResponse` somehow. Ugh.

```
QueryResponse queryResponse = new QueryResponse(namedList, client);
```

And, of course, the `queryResponse` isn't fully populated (e.g. `elapsedTime` isn't set). Am I missing something? Seems like there has to be an easier way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! This call seems to address my concern:

```
QueryResponse queryResponse = queryRequest.process(solrClient);
```